# mysql round not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I am working on an invoice webpage and I just realized by rounding is off when getting the value from mysql database.

I have tried using round, truncate, ceil but have not been able to get the correct number.

Example:

ItemTotal = 525
ItemQuantity = 1
Taxable=true
Rate=6.5

So the calculation should come out to be 559.125 which should be rounded to 559.13 however my query is rounding to 559.12.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

```
select invoices.ID,ClientName, ClientStreetAddress,CONCAT(ClientCity,', ',ClientState,' ',ClientZip) as ClientCityStateZip, SUM(ROUND(IF(Taxable = true, (ItemTotal*ItemQuantity)+((ItemTotal*ItemQuantity)*(Rate/100)), ItemTotal*ItemQuantity),2)) as TotalAmount, ClientEmail, DateTime, ExpirationDate, EmailSent from `invoices` invoices inner join `invoiceitem` item on item.InvoiceID = invoices.ID where EmailSent=1 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY DateTime DESC, ID DESC
```

Comment: image too small to read

Comment: My eyesight is not what it was. In fact, I don't think I could ever have read that. Post the code, not a bad screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROUND(amount,2)` instead of `TRUNCATE` as you have used in you query.

```
SUM(ROUND(IF(Taxable=true , ()),2))
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

#### See an [working example here](http://sqlize.com/fMqAULB7ZH)

Comment: round gives me the same result as truncate.

Comment: Try the opposite `ROUND(SUM`